# Com CSS existe alguma forma de mudar o estilo do Text-Overflow:Ellipsis?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, ux

Imagine que tenho uma situação onde o texto é maior que o *container*, então vou usar `text-overflow: ellipsis` para colocar os 3 pontinhos `...` mostrando que o texto continua e ali dentro do *container* tem mais conteúdo, até aí tudo bem.

O problema é que eu quero customizar os meus `...` com outra `color` e queria em `bold`. Mão não achei uma maneira de fazer isso. Eu gostaria de algo como a imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de customizar o `text-overflow: ellipsis` em um estilo diferente do já aplicado no *container* com o texto?

O que tenho até o momento é isso:

```css
div.b {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 70px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que e isto que queres. retirado [overflow ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594018/styling-dots-on-text-overflow-ellipsis/37594427#37594427)

1. tens que rescrever o default text-styling
2. vais precisar `<span>` (ou qualquer outro) elemento

```css
.text-overflow
{
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;

  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text-overflow > span
{
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-overflow">
<span>Here is some very nice text indeed. So this is getting long</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Como a resposta não parece ser originalmente sua, por favor, tenha bom senso e referencie a fonte de onde retirou a solução (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37594427/1452488). E, aproveitando, na pergunta existe apenas um elemento no HTML, na sua solução foram necessários dois. Quais são as implicações (positivas e negativas) de se fazer assim?

Comment: Ok funcionou mas vc poderia explicar porque funcionou? Isso que vc colocou já tinha na resposta em inglês citada pelo Anderson. E se meu componente não aceitar uma tag extra dentro dele, tem alguma solução para ele não quebrar?

Comment: como referido no ingles (If the ellipsis is taking the color of the div, then make the div the color you want the ellipsis to be, and use .color to set the initial text black.) se a elipsis esta a ter a cor da div entao muda a cor na div para a cor que queres

Comment: porque nao haveria de aceitar uma tag extra nao existe limite de tag no html pelo que eu sei se isto for o que estas a perguntar se for por questões de conteúdo podes sempre por um display: inline block ( e assim o conteudo fica em linha) podes tambem usar white-space: nowrap; que evita quebra no espaço branco

Comment: Acho que o que estão tentando te explicar é que o importante não é explicar só "como fazer" mas explicar "porque funciona" ou "como funciona". Uma resposta com maior qualidade é importante, pois esta página será visitada no futuro por outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida. Entende? Não é nada pessoal.

Comment: eu apenas respondi a pergunta dele quando vi a resposta por baixo nos comentários corrigi o meu post e pus a referencia ao post do ingles não disse nada apenas corrigi  pois sou novo aqui e percebi o errado se quiserem dar um resposta mais completa estão a vontade a pessoa que fez a pergunta tem a possibilidade de dar os seus pontos a quem lhe responder de maneira mais correcta eu apenas dei uma referencia

Comment: É isso que quis dizer, a sua resposta é boa. Não conheço uma forma de fazer o que o autor da pergunta pede, por isso não vou responder. O que estou tentando dizer é que sua resposta já é boa, só precisa de mais informações.